# How to resolve blank passowrd field issue in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

Can anybody resolve my one issue.I want to save all of my values in sqlite database.I have name,emailid and password field.when i clicked on submit button only name and email-id has stored in database bit i found that password filed is showing blank.I am using rails version-4.0.2 and ruby 1.9.3.The codes are given below.

views/users/index.html.erb:

```
<h1>This is index page</h1>
<center>
<p>Enter data</p>
 <div class="option">
   <p><%= link_to "Click here to enter data",users_new_path %></p>
   <p><%= link_to "Display data",users_display_path%></p>
 </div>
 </center>
```

views/users/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Enter your data here</h1>
<center>
  <%= form_for @user ,:url => {:action => "create"} do |f| %>
  <div class="div_reg">
    <p>
      <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" >username </label>&nbsp;
      <%= f.text_field:name,placeholder:"Enter your user name" %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" >Email </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <%= f.text_field:email,placeholder:"enter your email" %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" >Password </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <%= f.password_field:password,placeholder:"Enteryour password" %>
    </p>
    <center>
      <%= f.submit "Submit",:class => 'btn-custom' %>
    </center>
    <div class="back_btn">
      <a href="/users/index"><button type="button" class="btn-custom " style="cursor:pointer;">Back</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
      <% end %>
</center>
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <ul class="Signup_Errors">
      <% for message_error in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message_error %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

controller/users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
  def new
@user=User.new
  end
  def create
@user=User.new(users_param);
    if @user.save
 flash[:notice]="You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]="valid"
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      flash[:alert]="You have not signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]="invalid"
      redirect_to :action => 'new'
    end
  end
  private
  def users_param
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
  end
def display

end

end
```

model/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :password, :confirmation => true
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
end
```

migrate\20150102052336_create_users.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a password_confirmation field

```
<%= f.password_field :password %> 
<%= f.password_field> :password_confirmation %>
```

add also add it into the permitted parameters

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
```

PS: I recommend looking up devise gem, once you figured how to create your own signup/login implementation..

Comment: Hello user3243476 thanks for helping me and providing some solution.But i have one doubt,if one does not need any password confirmation field ,then error can not be resolved.Can you please tell me now i have just name,email,password in my migration file,if i will add one more password_confirmation:string how i will update it.

Comment: @subhra the password_confirmation would not be saved in the database. it is caused by this line **validates :password, :confirmation => true** it is used to make sure that the user has input the proper password. no need for password_confirmation in migration. It is just for validation purposes.

Comment: Thanks a lot user3243476 for such type of help.

Comment: Yes actually i am totally new to SO as well as ROR. extremely sorry if any mistake i have done.